# Can Cat6A connector fit to normal gigabit network switch?

Tags: networking, cable, cat6, rj45

Cat 6A cable is thicker than Cat6 cable.  For a Cat6 cable and connector, we can plug into any network switch that has RJ45 connector even a 100Mbps network switch.

Just wonder if I use Cat6A cable and Cat6A connector, can I plug it into the normal RJ45 network port?  Will it fit since it's cable size if much thicker.

Comment: If the connector is an RJ45 connector, it will connect to a standard jack. If not, not.

Comment: I find this to be an interesting question. We have had many randomly dropped connections when using Cat 6a cables connecting to ProCurve 2810 and similar Gigabit switches.

The manual states compatibility with IEEE 802.3ab but I could not find whether Cat6a is supposed to be compatible. I really do wonder whether RJ45 is RJ45 in those cases or not.